# How To Appropriately Type a Variable Using React's useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How would I appropriately type variables in `useState`?

Below, basically `alert` needs to be `"success" | "warning" | "error" | "info"`

```
const [alertValue, setAlertValue] = useState("error");

<TextField
   label="Error State"
   message="this is an ERROR message"
   alert={alertValue} // error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type "success" | "warning" | "error" | "info";
   onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useState` hook is a generic function. You can supply the type when you call it. For example:

```
type AlertStatus = "success" | "warning" | "error" | "info"

const [alertValue, setAlertValue] = useState<AlertStatus>("error");
```

You should use the same property type defined for the `alert` property of the `TextField` component.